# Do these methods create new database and collections in MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

From Web Development with Go by Shiju Varghese

> To perform CRUD operations into MongoDB, an object of `*mgo.Collection` is created, which represents the MongoDB collection. You can create an object of `*mgo.Collection` by calling method `C` of `*mgo.Database`.
>
> The `mgo.Database` type represents the named database that can be
>   created by calling the `DB` method of `*mgo.Session`.
>
> Listing 8-5 accesses the MongoDB collection named "categories".
>
> Listing 8-5.  Accessing a MongoDB Collection
>
> ```
> c := session.DB("taskdb").C("categories")
> ```

Do the `DB` and `C` methods create database object and collection object in Go programs both

- for existing database and existing collection in a MongoDB server?
- for noexisting database and nonexisting collection, so that the methods will create new database and collection in a MongoDB server, which will be named as the arguments to the methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In MongoDB, a new DB and collection will be *created* **only** after a write operation, **after inserting first document** in a specific database and collection.

In MongoDB there is no `CREATE TABLE` like command/function, no need for that.

Your code does not *create* a collection since is not inserting new documents in new collection. In your code you don't need to worry about creating dbs or collections